# How to add word from input to another input form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am creating an ajax live search, I am using fill function. so when I clicked the word that pop up when I search it will fill to another input form. but I want when it fill its not replace the older word.

for example I have `input1` and `input2`. `input1` is for search and `input2` is for fill the word that i choice. for example i already choice `word1` from `input1`. `word1` will fill `input2`.

like this `input2 = word1`

but when i search another word in `input1` i want that word i choice not replace `input2` but add it. for example i choice `word2` so in `input2` will be

like this input2 = `word1, word2`

here my live search script

```
function fill(Value) {
   $('#tag_list').val(Value);
   $('#display').hide();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#tag").keyup(function() {
       $('#display').show();
       var name = $('#tag').val();
       if (name == "") {
           $("#display").html("");
           $("#display").hide();
       }
       else {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "../cari/tag.php",
               data: {
                   search: name     
               },
               success: function(html) {
                   $("#display").html(html).show();     
               }     
           });     
       }     
   });

});
```

my tag.php code

```
<div class="result" onclick='fill("<?php echo $caris['id_t']; ?>,")'>
```

Comment: from where you are calling `fill` function?

Comment: tag.php with onclick

Comment: just remove the old value using '$('#tag_list').val("");' and then assign the new value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append values like below

```
function fill(Value) {
   var $tagList = $('#tag_list');
   var previousVal = $tagList.val();
   if(previousVal) {
      previousVal += ", ";
   }
   $tagList.val(previousVal  + Value);
   $('#display').hide();
}
```

Comment: it fill like this , 2, 3

Comment: @Jazuly what u want? without comma separated?

Comment: like this `2, 3` not `, 2, 3`

Answer (score 1):

Your can use **[Addition assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment)** :

> The addition assignment operator adds the value of the right operand
>   to a variable and assigns the result to the variable. The types of the
>   two operands determine the behavior of the addition assignment
>   operator. Addition or concatenation is possible. See the addition
>   operator for more details.

***Syntax***

```
Operator: x += y 
Meaning:  x  = x + y
```

for your case :

```js
var query = '';

  
$('#search').on('click',function(){
  fill();
});
function fill() {
    query += $('#input1').val() + ',';
    $('#input2').val(query.slice(0,-1));
  /* The slice function will remove the last caractere from string ',' */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input1" id="input1">
<input type="text" name="input2" id="input2">

<button id="search">search</button>
```